# GitHub Actions (Workflows) Bug - Billing Issue

Tags: github, github-actions

Wanted to use the **GitHub Actions** inside my project on GitHub but after I clicked on the **Actions** tab on the project it gave me this bug message 
"***GitHub Actions workflows can't be executed on this repository. 
Actions is not available for legacy per-repository billing plans. Please visit your billing settings to upgrade your account.***"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If you are wondering why GitHub Actions suddenly stopped working for your open/closed source repository being it organizational or private, you may find this useful

Kindly go to the **billing section** https://github.com/organizations/YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NAME/settings/billing for **organization** or
 Go to the **billing section** https://github.com/settings/billing for **personal**, now

**Under the Billing Section** 
***Switch billing from $0/month to $0/year***, go back to your repository's **Actions** tab to see if it took effect. If it did, then you are sorted
 Else 
 Kindly contact github's support here https://support.github.com/contact for help. Thank you